# how to prove this expression (preferably by induction)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

for all integers n>=1 if A and B1 ,B2,B3,...
are any sets!

$$\cup_{i=1}^n(A\times B_i)=A\times\cup_{i=1}^nB_i$$

induction way is better.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1$ we have $A \cap B_1 = A \cap B_1$, so just an identity.
For $n=2 : (A \cap B_1) \cup (A \cap B_2) = A \cap (B_1 \cup B_2).$
I hope this is obvious too, you can prove this formula by Venn diagram.
So we showed that formula is correct for $n = 2$ and need to show that if $\cup_{i=1}^n (A \cap B_i) = A \cap (\cup_{i=1}^n B_i)$, then $\cup_{i=1}^{n+1} (A \cap B_i) = A \cap (\cup_{i=1}^{n+1} B_i)$.
$A \cap (\cup_{i=1}^{n+1} B_i) = A \cap (B_1 \cup B_2 \cup \dots \cup B_n \cup B_{n+1}) = A \cap ((\cup_{i=1}^n B_i) \cup B_{n+1})$.
Now apply formula we got for $n=2$, substituiting $B_1 \rightarrow \cup_{i=1}^n B_i$ and $B_2 \rightarrow B_{n+1}$:
$A \cap ((\cup_{i=1}^n B_i) \cup B_{n+1}) = (A \cap (\cup_{i=1}^n B_i)) \cup (A \cap B_{n+1}) = [$by our inductional assumption$] = \cup_{i=1}^n (A \cap B_i) \cup (A \cap B_{n+1}) = \cup_{i=1}^{n+1} (A \cap B_i).$  Q.E.D.